# Boolean 'and' search within ElasticSearch.Nest client

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have an elastic search query that is returning what I'd consider an 'or' search. The elastic search Nest client is v4.0.30319 and the elastic search server is version 1.6.0. The 'and' search is on the index 'sc'. An equivalent sql statement running "select * from clients where profile like '%business%' and ... profile like '%Helping%' " against the corresponding database table in question would return no records. How would I change the following query and/or code to perform a boolean 'and' search?

```
query = 'id:("7ee683c2-19eb-45c6-9ca8-985379ce34dd") 
         AND role:("User","OrganizationAdmin","SystemAdmin","follower") 
         AND (  
              sc:("business*") 
              and  sc:("objectives*") 
              and  sc:("memorable*") 
              and  sc:("Keith*") 
              and  sc:("Lawyer*") 
              and  sc:("accountant*") 
              and  sc:("Helping*") )' ;

result = _client.Search<T>(
 t => t.Types(type).Index(_index).Query(
    qt => qt.QueryString(qs => qs.Query(query).OnFields(fields))).Filter(
        x => x.Range(y => y.From(fromDate).To(toDate).OnField(rangeOnField))
    ).SortDescending(orderByField).SortDescending("_score").Skip(skipRecord).Take(pageSize));
```

I discovered that result.ConnectionStatus contains the raw elastic search query which is really helpful. Using the base query and then adding in the boolean criteria for sc by hand gives a raw search criteria as

```
    {
      "from": 0,
      "size": 100,
      "sort": {
        "cd": "desc",
        "_score": "desc"
      },
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "id:(\"7ee683c2-19eb-45c6-9ca8-985379ce34dd\") AND role:(\"User\",\"OrganizationAdmin\",\"SystemAdmin\",\"follower\") AND ( sc:(\"business*\") AND sc:(\"objectives*\")  AND sc:(\"memorable*\")  AND  sc:(\"Keith*\") AND  sc:(\"Lawyer*\") AND  sc:(\"accountant*\") AND  sc:(\"Helping*\") ) ",
          "fields": [
            "id",
            "sc",
            "role",
            "nm"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "cd": {
            "from": "19160709",
            "to": "21160709"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

which returns no results so I'm guessing there is something strange going on with the code.

Comment: The example that you have here won't compile; Would you be able to provide a working example? Additionally, what version of NEST are you using and what version of Elasticsearch are you targeting?

Comment: I'm maintaining the code @RussCam so getting a compilable version will take me a while. I have discovered how to get the raw elastic search json string which is useful. The nest client is v4.0.30319. The elastic search version is 1.6.0

Comment: ok cool. If you're using Elasticsearch 1.6.0 then you can use any minor version of NEST 1.x, although I'd recommend always using the latest 1.x version which is currently 1.8.3  - https://www.nuget.org/packages/NEST/1.8.3. With the lowlevel client that is accessible on `ElasticClient` via `ElasticClient.LowLevel`, you can send raw json strings or anonymous types for the request if necessary - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/1.x/building-requests.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the query needed to be changed. 'and' needed to be 'AND'.

This query

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 100,
    "sort": {
        "cd": "desc",
        "_score": "desc"
    },
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "id:(\"7ee683c2-19eb-45c6-9ca8-985379ce34dd\") AND role:(\"User\",\"OrganizationAdmin\",\"SystemAdmin\",\"follower\") AND ( sc:(\"business*\") AND sc:(\"objectives*\")  AND sc:(\"memorable*\")  AND  sc:(\"Keith*\") AND  sc:(\"Lawyer*\") AND  sc:(\"accountant*\") AND  sc:(\"Helping*\") ) ",
            "fields": [
                "id",
                "sc",
                "role",
                "nm"
            ]
        }
    },
    "filter": {
        "range": {
            "cd": {
                "from": "19160709",
                "to": "21160709"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

worked returning no records but this query

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 100,
    "sort": {
        "cd": "desc",
        "_score": "desc"
    },
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "id:(\"7ee683c2-19eb-45c6-9ca8-985379ce34dd\") AND role:(\"User\",\"OrganizationAdmin\",\"SystemAdmin\",\"follower\") AND (   sc:(\"business\")  and sc:(\"objectives\")  and sc:(\"memorable\")  and sc:(\"Keith\")  and sc:(\"Lawyer\")  and sc:(\"accountant\")  and sc:(\"Helping\") ) ",
            "fields": [
                "id",
                "sc",
                "role",
                "nm"
            ]
        }
    },
    "filter": {
        "range": {
            "cd": {
                "from": "19160709",
                "to": "21160709"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

failed returning 3 records. The only difference is the case of the 'and's in the bracket for the field 'sc'.

Comment: Lucene's querystring format can be a little bit tricky :) You can always expand it out to the more explicit from of a `bool` query if it would be clearer. An additional change that you may consider is moving this to a `filtered` query, with the `query` part being your `querystring` query, and the `filter` part being your `range` filter (query). The top level `filter` (now called `post_filter` in 2.x onwards) serves a slightly different purpose - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-post-filter.html